# How to use redux framework sorter option?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

Good evening, I have managed to embed redux framework in a WP theme and everything works great, but I'm more a designer than a programmer and I would like to use the option type "sorter" (https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/wiki/Fields#sorter) to "get_template_part" in the homepage based on the enabled column and the order saved.

My output is for print_r($redux_options['home_blocks']['enabled']):

```
Array
(
    [placebo] => placebo
    [slider] => Slider
    [highlights] => Highlights
    [services] => Services
    [staticpage] => Static Page
)
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
slider = get_template_part('templates/content','slider');
highlights = get_template_part('templates/content','highlights');
services = get_template_part('templates/content','services');
staticpage = get_template_part('templates/content','staticpage');
```

Of course having the same order as the array and if present in the enabled column.

I have taken a look at shoestrap3 to see how they managed to make the sorter look but to this option is not used in the latest version (3.1.0.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
global $redux_options;
$layout = $redux_options['home_blocks']['enabled'];

if ($layout): foreach ($layout as $key=>$value) {

    switch($key) {

        case 'slider': get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'slider' );
        break;

        case 'highlights': get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'highlights' );
        break;

        case 'services': get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'services' );
        break;

        case 'staticpage': get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'staticpage' );    
        break;  

    }

}

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lead dev behind Redux here. Issues like this are best served on our issue tracker: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/ReduxFramework/issues

However, the answer to your question lies in our new documents site: http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/fields/sorter/

That will get you what you need.

If you want to learn how to use Redux more, we're having a webinar tomorrow: https://www2.gotomeeting.com/register/797085722

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Dovy, I'm already registered to the webinar for about 2 weeks now :). 
I'm looking for a more detailed solution for my problem. If I can't find a solution, I'll open a "question" on the issue tracker posted above. 
Good luck tonight at the webinar

Comment: The accepted answer's solution is much more functional than the print_r used in the docs, and is probably worth adding.

Comment: Added to the docs.  http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/fields/sorter/